# Connect multiple databases using JDBC

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am using a code like that to connect to database in Java:

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
String user = "root";
String password = "Pass";
```

I get data from database by executing sql query:

```
String sqlQuery = "Select queryID from test_data_solution";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
...
```

But I need to connect another database model in MySQL server. I will use inner join from a table which is in another database. How can I connect to or get data from another database in the same Java program? I want to run the code like:

```
select * 
from mydb.test_data_solution 
inner join anotherdb.queryid_tokensid 
    on test_data_solution.queryid = queryid_tokensid.queryid
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can reference tables by specifying the database they are in and do cross-database queries.  E.g.

```
String sqlQuery = "Select t.queryID, x.someCol from mydb.test_data_solution t JOIN otherdb.some_table x ON t.queryID = x.queryID";
```

Comment: except that gives "error: mydb.otherdb.some_table does not exist"